# Cannot get all children Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 public void getData(){
        DatabaseReference childRef = users.child(userID);
        childRef.child(nameOfEntry).setValue("new");

        childRef.child(nameOfEntry).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for(DataSnapshot dsp: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.i("Sandash", dsp.getKey());

                }
```

I have the datasnapshot set up but it is literally not giving any response in the logs. What is wrong with this?

Comment: can you take a snapshot of your firebase db

Comment: Are you sure your user has read permission to the data. To detect this, handle `onCancelled()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/22652/detect-errors-when-reading-data-on-android#t=201610181319008269757